# In KDB, how do I sum the previous 3 numbers in a list?

Tags: kdb

Say I have a list of numbers:

```
j: (til 40)*9

0 9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90 99 108 117 126 135 144 153 162 171 180 189 198 207 216 225 234 243 252 261 270 279 288 297 306 315 324 333 342 351
```

What's the most elegant way to get the sum of the previous 3 (or n) numbers in the list? (Ideally considering large RAM constrained lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
q)3 msum j
0 9 27 54 81 108 135 162 189 216 243 270 297 324 351 378 405 432 459 486 513 ..
```